# Issue on Inserting JavaScript Array Data into MySQL Database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

Can you please take a look at following snippets and let me know why I am not able to insert array values into the database. In Js file I have:

```
 <script>
        var arr = ["foo", "2015/11/04", "Jill", "Smith", "60"];
        var serializedArr = JSON.stringify( arr );
      $("#loader").on("click", function(){
        var upload = $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "loader.php",
                            data: {array:serializedArr},
                            cache: false,
                            beforeSend: function() {
                            }
        });
});
```

and in PHP file

```
<?php
   define ( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );
   define ( 'DB_USER', 'root' );
   define ( 'DB_PASSWORD', '' );
   define ( 'DB_NAME', 'dbapp' );

 //$array = json_decode($_POST['array']);
$array = $_POST['array'];
//Open a new connection to the MySQL server
$mysqli = new mysqli('DB_HOST','DB_USER','DB_PASSWORD','DB_NAME');

$arr_one =   $mysqli->real_escape_string($array[0]);
$arr_two =   $mysqli->real_escape_string($array[1]);
$arr_three = $mysqli->real_escape_string($array[2]);
$arr_four =  $mysqli->real_escape_string($array[3]);
$arr_five =  $mysqli->real_escape_string($array[4]);

if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
}

//MySqli Insert Query
$insert_row = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `models` (name, date, nip, tip, age) VALUES($arr_one, $arr_two, $arr_three, $arr_four, $arr_five)");

if($insert_row){
    print 'Success! ID of last inserted record is : ' .$mysqli->insert_id .'<br />'; 
}else{
    die('Error : ('. $mysqli->errno .') '. $mysqli->error);
}
// close connection 
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

I tried both

```
$array = json_decode($_POST['array']);
```

and

```
$array = $_POST['array'];
```

but I am not able to load the data and even no error message on page?!

Comment: I'd expect `$mysqli = new mysqli('DB_HOST','DB_USER','DB_PASSWORD','DB_NAME');` to fail

Comment: @hjpotter92, thanks but what do you mean?

Comment: Do you see anything in the console as the ajax request is made? As @hjpotter92 said, the call to mysqli uses strings rather than the previously defined constants

Comment: No , nothing in console!

Comment: What exactly is in `$_POST['array']` when you process the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use the defined constants instead of strings when establishing the connection.
2. Use prepared statements instead of passing variables inside the query.
3. As stated in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33538958/1190388), you are trying to access index of a string variable (since the data sent was JSON string).
4. Use `success`, `error` handles in the ajax call, to output the results/errors to console.

So, you'll need to `json_decode` the received data before doing anything with it.

---

```
$array = json_decode( $_POST['array'] );
$mysqli = new mysqli( DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME );
```

---

```
$insert_row_stmt = $mysqli->prepare( "INSERT INTO `models` (name, date, nip, tip, age) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$insert_row_stmt->bind_param( 'ssssi', 
    $array[0],
    $array[1],
    $array[2],
    $array[3],
    $array[4]
);
$insert_row = $insert_row_stmt->execute();
```

---

```
var upload = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "loader.php",
    data: {array:serializedArr},
    cache: false,
    success: function(d) {
        console.log(d);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks hjpotter92 this is working BUT there is one issue here! the code is inserting `0` for `name` which must be `foo` but the others are correct

Comment: @Behseini Put a `var_dump($array);` and check the result you get.

Comment: but I am posting the data! then how can I use the `var_dump($array);`

Comment: By putting `console.log` in a success handler of your `$.ajax` call.

Comment: i really like to learn this debugging! so `console.log` what?

Comment: @Behseini I've added the `success` handler code in my post.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are JSON.stringify'ing the array before sending it through the AJAX request. That means array = "["foo", "2015/11/04", "Jill", "Smith", "60"]", which is technically not a valid JSON object.

Try wrapping the array in a js object then stringifying it. such as

```
var arr = {data: ["foo", "2015/11/04", "Jill", "Smith", "60"] };
```

then try

```
$array = json_decode($_POST['array']).data;
```

Comment: Thanks Christooher but I got confused here! so how about `data: {array:serializedArr},` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="loader"></div>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var arr = ["foo", "2015/11/04", "Jill", "Smith", "60"];
    $("#loader").load('load.php',{arr:arr});
</script>
```

load.php:

```
 <?php
       $arr = $_POST['arr'];
       $insert_row = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `models` (name, date, nip, tip, age)
                      VALUES($arr[1], $arr[2], $arr[3], $arr[4], $arr[5])");
    ?>
```

you can add values like this in database.